# Encoding a dictionary in URL Encoding

Tags: dictionary, url, stripe-payments, urlencode

I'm trying to attach a payment source in Stripe. To do so, I want to directly pass payment info. This is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#customer_create_bank_account). If you read description of source parameter, you'll understand my requirement.I want to attach dictionary of params to source param.

My question is how should I attach the params like `object`, `account_number` etc. which are supposed to be a dictionary under `source` param

PS: I'm trying to hit this api using Postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out a way of doing it. `params` are attached in the following format.

Request Type: `POST`
and to attach a source `param` with dictionary format, `param` is `source[object]`, `source[account_number]` etc.

Comment: While this will work, it's going to put you under a higher scope for PCI compliance. Even as a large company you likely do not want to do this and you should instead tokenize client-side: https://stripe.com/docs/security#pci-dss-guidelines

Comment: As I'm doing in iOS, they don't have any native SDK page to handle this and hence there will be API calls anyways.

Comment: The iOS SDK definitely handles bank account details though https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/b115c6d728fed241e5a7eb114dd22f714c54481a/Tests/Tests/STPBankAccountFunctionalTest.m

Comment: Oh didn't knew about that. Thanks for that info.